# Como separar com condicoes em R?

Tags: r

O meu objetivo e separar um endereco com certas condicoes

Eu resultado final seria assim:

```
id   Cod_postal Zona    Tipo_estrada    Nome_estrada    numero  bloco   apartamento extra
1000 8400       Lisboa  Avenida         Ameixoeira 5    8       NA      ap.A        NA
```

Mas como eu fiz nao separa bem:

```
id   Cod_postal Zona    Tipo_estrada    Nome_estrada    numero       bloco  apartamento extra
1000 8400       Lisboa  Avenida                         Ameixoeira   5      8           ap.
```

Ate agora o meu codigo e esse aqui:

```
  select(Id,Cod_postal,cod_x) %>% 
  separate(cod_x, into = c("Cod_postal","Zona","Tipo_estrada","Nome_estrada","numero","bloco","aparamento","extra"), sep = " ") -> test
```

Acho que e suposto usar o mutate ou algo do genero.

Edit: Amostra

```
1000 8400 Lisboa Avenida Ameixoeira 5 8 ap. A
```

Ps:(Eu sei que facilmente era separar com um espaco mas eu nao posso alterar a base de dados)

Ps2:O que eu pretendo e saber como separar pelo espaco e como exigir uma condicao de um certo campo (Por exemplo numero so pode ter numero)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Bom dia. Para ajudar, seria necessário que vc adicionasse uma amostra da base para saber como a mesma está organizada.

Comment: eu tenho um endereco e pretendo separa-lo como indiquei no 1 treco de codigo, mas da maneira que eu fiz nao esta separando bem

Comment: O endereço está em uma "string" única ? Segue algum padrão ? Qual a entrada do dado ?

Comment: Adicionei mais informacao no edit

Comment: Sem um separador fica difícil a cidade pode ter um nome Lisboa ou nome composto 'Vila Nova de Gaia' p ex , aqui no Brasil é comum lugares sem número em zonas rurais , não tem como separar na origem ?

Comment: nem por isso porque sao cerca de 200.000 registos e separar 1 por 1 iria demorar semanas

Comment: Olá @nmexlxc , Bem vindo ao [pt.so], para entender melhor o funcionamento do site vale apena dar uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Agora especificamente sobre sua pergunta, como ela é sobre [tag:r], deixo um link que pode ajuda-lo a melhora-la e dessa forma ajudar a comunidade a entender melhor sua duvida - [Como criar um exemplo mínimo reproduzível em R](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/3774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na falta de um exemplo com a estrutura das variáveis "**bloco**" e "**extra**" fica difícil contemplar essas variáveis. No entanto, segue uma sugestão para separar as demais variáveis.

A função `separate()` é, de fato, uma boa opção. O problema é que vc precisa (se entendi corretamente) que o nome da estrada venha junto com seu número; da mesma forma que o termo "ap." venha agregado ao que se segue. A questão é que não dá para usar o separador `" "` porque ele separaria estas duas circunstâncias acima mencionada.

Uma possível solução seria criar algum caracter que separasse os termos que vc deseja, sem interferir no espaço em branco entre o termo estrada e o número que vem em seguida, e do termo "ap." do que vem em seguida.

Para este exemplo vou utilizar o *underscore* para separar os termos de interesse. E para adicionar este *underscore* vou utilizar a função `str_replace()`.

A função `str_replace()` tem os seguintes parâmetros:

- `string =`  com a string a ser manipulada;
- `pattern =`  o padrão que será objeto da substituição;
- `replacement =`  com a estrutura que se pretende.

Assim, primeiro crio um exemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(endereco = c("1000 8400 Lisboa Avenida Ameixoeira 5 8 ap. A"))

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  endereco                                     
  <chr>                                        
1 1000 8400 Lisboa Avenida Ameixoeira 5 8 ap. A
```

E aplico a função `str_replace()`:

```
df_2 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(endereco = str_replace(string = endereco,
                                  pattern = "(.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*\\s.*) (.*) (.*\\s.*)",
                                  replacement = "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\4_\\5_\\6_\\7"))
```

A interpreção do parâmetro `pattern =`  é a seguinte:

- cada `()` representa uma coluna. Como a intenção é dividir a string "**endereco**" em 7 colunas, criamos, 7 conjuntos de `()`. Ficaria assim:

  - `pattern = "()()()()()()()"`
- do lado de fora do parêntese, fica aquilo que não será capturado. No caso, não queremos capturar os espaços. Então a continuação do preenchimento é:

  - `pattern = "() () () () () () ()"`
- e agora, informamos qual será o conteúdo de cada coluna. Com base no exemplo que vc deu, a seguinte estrura se adequa bem:

  - `pattern = "(.*) (.*) (.*) (.*) (.*\\s.*) (.*) (.*\\s.*)"`

O `.*` significa qualquer coisa em qualquer quantidade.

Assim, uma leitura do padrão acima seria:

- `(.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*\\s.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de qualquer coisa seguido de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*)`  qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de;
- `(.*\\s.*)` qualquer coisa *seguido* de espaço em branco seguido de qualquer coisa.

resultado:

```
df_2

# A tibble: 1 × 1
  endereco                                     
  <chr>                                        
1 1000_8400_Lisboa_Avenida_Ameixoeira 5_8_ap. A
```

Agora utiliza-se o `_` como separador na função `separate()`:

```
df_2 %>% 
  separate(col = endereco, 
           into = c("id",
                    "Cod_postal",
                    "Zona",
                    "Tipo_estrada",
                    "Nome_estrada",
                    "numero",
                    "apartamento"),
           sep = "_", 
           convert = TRUE)
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 7
     id Cod_postal Zona   Tipo_estrada Nome_estrada numero apartamento
  <int>      <int> <chr>  <chr>        <chr>         <int> <chr>      
1  1000       8400 Lisboa Avenida      Ameixoeira 5      8 ap. A
```